# bash vs. tcsh alias argument passing

Tags: bash, tcsh

I used to have this alias in tcsh to find files on the filesystem.

```
alias findf 'find . -name \!* -print'
```

How do I write this in bash shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a shell function and not an alias (assuming `\!*` is a placeholder for the alias "arguments").

To accept just a single argument:

```
findf() {
    find . -name "$1" -print
}
```

To accept any number of arguments (not that this is very useful for the argument to `-name`):

```
findf() {
    find . -name "$@" -print
}
```

Comment: so I don't have to use the `alias` directive? I am getting `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: No, you don't use `alias` for functions.